# Clicking a phone number in browser results in "Open XDG-Open?"

Tags: google-chrome, linux-mint

Is there a way to cause xdg-open to open a specific web url when a phone number is clicked?  The url I would want it to use is"https://voice.google.com/calls"

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can create a script/program that opens the default browser with that URL. Then you register this script/program with a tool like gio to make it the default handler for the URL scheme (`tel`). How do this last step depends on which desktop environment you're using. Here are my notes: https://fredrik.wendt.se/2014/11/08/uri-scheme-desktop-entry/

In short here are the steps necessary:

- make the browser start a specific program when you click `tel:` links - currently your browser uses the default program, `xdg-open`, as the browser doesn't have a specific program associated with `tel:` links **
- assuming we're OK with involving `xdg-open` to handle `tel:` links, the next step is to register your program that handles the click so that `xdg-open` knows that your program can handle `tel:` links
- make your program the default program for `xdg-open` to use, when passed a `tel:` link

** Yes, this means you could by-pass `xdg-open` completely, by registering your program directly in the browser, telling it "hey, my program X should handle all links starting with tel:". You can see some clues as how to do that in https://stackoverflow.com/a/7101222/153117

Comment: Thanks, now starts the journey to understand your solution, I am a noob.